# how to arrange a layout in a flex-box

Tags: css

I want to get this effect:
https://zapodaj.net/b589e3e13aade.png.html
But unfortunately something like this comes out to me, I am already tired of it with 3 hours someone can help?

```css
body {
  list-style: none;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.wrapper3 {
  display: flex;
}
.click {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 19px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.content2{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <li class="click"> <a class="box" href="#">Skorzystaj z ofert! </a></li>
      <div class="wrapper3">
      <li class="click2"> <a class="box" href="#">Informacje | </a></li>
      <li class="click3"> <a class="box" href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <li class="click4"> <a class="box" href="#">Zaloguj</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "Login" button does not center as it should

Comment: @Oliview which effect please make it more clear your desired output and also please add the code to the snippet so that one can see your output

Answer (score 0):

Just give some height to the `div` with class name `wrapper`. As shown in the code below.

```css
body {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper {
 /* Give Some height to this wrapper */ 
  height: 125px; 
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper3 {
  display: flex;
}
.click {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 19px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.content2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <li class="click"> <a class="box" href="#">Skorzystaj z ofert! </a></li>
      <div class="wrapper3">
        <li class="click2"> <a class="box" href="#">Informacje | </a></li>
        <li class="click3"> <a class="box" href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <li class="click4"> <a class="box" href="#">Zaloguj</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I cannot change the height

Comment: Why not? Give more context.